# What is the proper way to import jquery.inputmask?

Tags: typescript, webpack, jquery-inputmask

I'm having trouble importing [jquery.inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask) with webpack and TypeScript. There is some discussion at  [Question: build this with webpack/es6 #1115](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/issues/1115) :

> Here's how i just set things up with jqlite
>
> Import in your app like so:
>
> ```
> import InputMask from 'inputmask';
> ```
>
> to make the module available by that name you have to alias it and the
>   dep lib
>
> webpack config (using the jqlite dep lib, swap this out for jquery if
>   you use that instead):
>
> ```
> {
>   // ... your config +
>   resolve: {
>     alias: {
>       'inputmask.dependencyLib': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/jquery.inputmask/extra/dependencyLibs/inputmask.dependencyLib.jqlite.js'),
>       'inputmask': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/jquery.inputmask/dist/inputmask/inputmask.js')
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

I have a similar webpack config with jQuery instead of jqLite as the dependency:

```
alias: {
    "inputmask.dependencyLib": path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/jquery.inputmask/dist/inputmask/inputmask.dependencyLib.jquery.js'),
    "inputmask": path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/jquery.inputmask/dist/inputmask/inputmask.js')
}
```

With `import InputMask from "inputmask";` the TypeScript compiler throws an error:

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'inputmask'.

With `import "inputmask";` I get a runtime error when calling `$(element).inputmask(mask);`:

> TypeError: $(...).inputmask is not a function

Is there something wrong with the config, or is it a problem with the library itself?

Comment: You have to put `import "inputmask";` in your entry point and then you can import the elements of the module in your classes with `import InputMask from "inputmask";`

Comment: @iberbeu I get the same TS2307 error when doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Over the weekend someone asked [a similar question on GitHub](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/issues/1308), and a solution was posted too.

The full gist (with comments) can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/ksrb/47f9124c2f5be13f39dc645405a12608). Two additional aliases are needed:

```
"jquery": path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js'),
"inputmask.dependencyLib": path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/jquery.inputmask/dist/inputmask/inputmask.dependencyLib.jquery.js'),
"inputmask": path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/jquery.inputmask/dist/inputmask/inputmask.js'),
"jquery.inputmask": path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/jquery.inputmask/dist/inputmask/jquery.inputmask.js')
```

Then to import the library, use `import "jquery.inputmask";`.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you want to get it to run for newer versions of inputmask/jquery. Some things have changed for inputmask. I was able to get it work with the following code:

package.json:

```
"webpack": "^5.1.3",

"inputmask": "^5.0.5",
"jquery": "^3.5.1",
```

webpack model.exports:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    'jquery': _path('../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery'),
    'inputmask': _path('../node_modules/inputmask/dist/jquery.inputmask'),
  },
},
```

ES6 import:

```
import 'inputmask';
import $ from 'jquery';
```